# Loading internal JSON data rather than from an external resource/file for a sunburst in d3

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I created a function that takes data from an arbitrary format and turns it into some nested JSON.

Currently in order to take this JSON and pass it to a function to create a sunburst, I am saving the data to a .json file and then loading it back in externally. I would like to avoid this step.

The JSON structure looks like below. I have roughly 15 main nodes, and as many ask 10 children for each of those.

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "data",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "converters",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "display",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "flex",
   "children": [
    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "physics",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "size": 593},
      {"name": "and", "size": 330},
      {"name": "average", "size": 287},
      {"name": "count", "size": 277},
      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
      {"name": "div", "size": 595},
      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
      {"name": "max", "size": 283},
      {"name": "min", "size": 283},
      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
      {"name": "not", "size": 386},
      {"name": "or", "size": 323},
      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
      {"name": "range", "size": 772},
      {"name": "select", "size": 296},
      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
      {"name": "update", "size": 307},
      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
      {"name": "where", "size": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
      {"name": "_", "size": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "scale",
   "children": [
    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "util",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
    {
     "name": "heap",
     "children": [
      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
    {
     "name": "math",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
    {
     "name": "palette",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "axis",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "controls",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
      {
       "name": "render",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "legend",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "distortion",
       "children": [
        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "encoder",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "filter",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
      {
       "name": "label",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "layout",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I am using a slightly modified pre-made sunburst creation function from Mike Bostock (Block 4063423) that looks like so:

```
var createSunburst = function()
{
    var width = 960,
    height = 800,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 50,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height * .52 + ")");

    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
        .sort(null)
        .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
        .value(function(d) { return 1; });

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
        .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
        .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    function format_name(d)
    {
        var name = d.name;
        return name;
    }


    d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(partition.nodes);
      var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
          .data(partition.nodes)
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; }) // hide inner ring
          .attr("d", arc)
          .style("stroke", "#fff")
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
          .style("fill-rule", "evenodd")
           .on("mouseover", function(d) {
              tooltip.html(function() {
                  var name = format_name(d);
                  return name;
             });
              return tooltip.transition()
                .duration(50)
                .style("opacity", 0.9);
            })
            // .on("mousemove", function(d) {
            //   return tooltip
            //     .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
            //     .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
            //})
            .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("opacity", 0);})
              .each(stash);
          

      d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
        var value = this.value === "count"
            ? function() { return 1; }
            : function(d) { return d.size; };

        path
            .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
          .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .attrTween("d", arcTween);
      });
    });

    // Stash the old values for transition.
    function stash(d) {
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.dx0 = d.dx;
    }

    // Interpolate the arcs in data space.
    function arcTween(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
      return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        a.x0 = b.x;
        a.dx0 = b.dx;
        return arc(b);
      };
    }

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
    
}
```

My JSON is formatted correctly and works when loaded externally. Assuming I bring the data into the `createSunburst` function as `inputData`, and I have a variable with the (I'm assuming to leave it parsed) json structure, what needs to be done to make this work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If understand correctly, you want to eliminate the step of loading data from external file i.e flare.json

- First remove the d3 json call
- Declare a variable root above variable path and assign the contents of the file to the variable. Don't use quotes.

  ```
  var root = {
     "name": "flare",
      "children": [
      {
      "name": "analytics",......}; // copy paste whatever is in the external file
  ```

That's all.